# Swap array elements in object by reference

Tags: javascript

I just found out that JavaScript properties are always returned by reference. I need their values.

I've got an object with an array as one of its properties. I need to swap two values within that array.

The code below is hugely simplified, the actual array contains objects, not just strings. My current workaround involves getting the two indexes of the Array. But I'm sensing I'm doing something wrong here.

Any advise? The code below is not my workaround, but my attempt of making something better. But nothing is changing within the array.

```
var obj = {
    arr: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
};

console.log(obj);

var source = obj.arr[0];
var destination = obj.arr[1];

obj.arr[0] = destination;
obj.arr[1] = source;

console.log(obj);
```

The stange thing is; the ouput is even b, a, c, d the first time.

Comment: Are you sure you need the values? It would involve cloning the entire object, unless you just need a primitive value.

Comment: Yes (I think so); I'm making a puzzle game. I've got an array of all the pieces. Each piece is an object with properties about it's position. I need to swap the positions of two pieces.

Comment: You just changed your question to match my answer - b,a,c,d is the expected result, what's the problem?

Comment: @Erik swapping the objects should suffice. See Justin's answer. If that doesn't work for you, we'll need to see more code.

Comment: Oh I see, your console log is probably showing the updates on the object, replace the console.log(obj) with console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) and you will see a,b,c,d the first time

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the array itself:

```
var source = obj.arr[0];
var destination = obj.arr[1];

obj.arr[0] = destination;
obj.arr[1] = source;
```